# Removing all but last non-zero sequence from numpy array

Tags: numpy

**The problem**

I have a 1-dimensional numpy array filled mostly with zeros but also containing some groups of non-zero values.

```
>> import numpy as np
>> a = np.zeros(10)
>> a[2:4] = 2
>> a[6:9] = 3
>> print a
[ 0.  0.  2.  2.  0.  0.  3.  3.  3.  0.]
```

I want to get the array that contains only the last non-zero group. In other words, all but the last non-zero group should be replaced by zeros. (The groups could be only 1 element long). Like so:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  3.  3.  3.  0.]
```

**Non-robust solution**

This seems to do the trick. Reverse the array and find the first index where the change between elements is negative. Then replace all subsequent elements with zero. Then flip back.  It's a bit long-winded:

```
>> b = a[::-1]
>> b[np.where(np.ediff1d(b) < 0)[0][0] + 1:] = 0
>> c = b[::-1]
>> print c
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  3.  3.  3.  0.]
```

**Fails for a specific case**

However, it is not robust and fails in the following case (because the where command returns an empty list of indices):

```
>> a = np.zeros(10)
>> a[0:4] = 2
>> print a
[ 2.  2.  2.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
>> b = a[::-1]
>> b[np.where(np.ediff1d(b) < 0)[0][0] + 1:] = 0
>> c = b[::-1]
>> print c

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-81-8cba57558ba8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/name/test1.py', wdir='C:/Users/name')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/name/test1.py", line 21, in <module>
    b[np.where(np.ediff1d(b) < 0)[0][0] + 1:] = 0

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

**Fix**

So I need to introduce an `if` clause:

```
>> b = a[::-1]
>> if len(np.where(np.ediff1d(b) < 0)[0]) > 0:
>>     b[np.where(np.ediff1d(b) < 0)[0][0] + 1:] = 0
>> c = b[::-1]
>> print c
[ 2.  2.  2.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

**UPDATE**
Following on from Divakar's excellent answer and mtrw's question, I would like to extend the specification. The method should also work if the input array has non-zero values that are negative *and* for groups of non-zero numbers that change within the grouping.

e.g. `np.array([1, 0, 0, 4, 5, 4, 5, 0, 0])`

This means methods where we check for a positive or negative difference between elements, in order to find the group boundaries, would not work so well.

Comment: Are the non-zero values also guaranteed to be greater than 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Since we are after elegance, let's *feed* ourselves a one-liner -

```
a[:(a[1:] > a[:-1]).cumsum().argmax()] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [605]: a
Out[605]: array([ 0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  0.])

In [606]: a[:(a[1:] > a[:-1]).cumsum().argmax()] = 0

In [607]: a
Out[607]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  0.])
```

---

**Approach #2**

Above approach assumes that the last group numbers are greater than `0`'s. If that's not the case and for cases where the non-zeros group might have different numbers, let's *feed* one more line to have a generic solution -

```
mask = a != 0
a[:(mask[1:] > mask[:-1]).cumsum().argmax()] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [667]: a
Out[667]: array([-1,  0,  0, -4, -5,  4, -5,  0,  0])

In [668]: mask = a != 0

In [669]: a[:(mask[1:] > mask[:-1]).cumsum().argmax()] = 0

In [670]: a
Out[670]: array([ 0,  0,  0, -4, -5,  4, -5,  0,  0])
```

Comment: Thanks that's great. I think it's too late to modify my question but I should have asked for arrays where the grouped numbers are not constant, like `a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 4, 5, 4, 5, 0, 0])`. Can your method be adapted for this case, ignoring the fact that the differences between neighbouring digits within a group can also be positive?

Comment: @feedMe In fact look at the second approach just added?